# AspNet Web Api token is not getting generated

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have some code in my Starup.cs

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
  OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthSerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
  {
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
      AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
      AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
      AllowInsecureHttp = true
  };
  app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthSerOptions);
  app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

and I have a login Action method which look like...

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<MyUser> Login(LoginModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {              
    return null;
  }

  var user = new MyUser()
  {
    UserName = model.UserName,
    PasswordHash = model.Password
  };
  var result = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);            
  return result;
}
```

Using Postman when I make a call to the above method I can see that get the body as

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Claims": [],
  "Logins": [],
  "Roles": [],
  "FirstName": null,
  "Id": "001fbdf7-a199-47df-ba34-b181886d084f",
  "UserName": "ABC",
  "PasswordHash": "AF7iQeV/11nrQ8LUXriGKw8eHEx1DDOnQrcANhndLto+FxDxH1xzPJqETXiII8HzOQ==",
"SecurityStamp": "b1a883d1-bbcc-4b67-a3fb-644e13c0cfd7"
}
```

**Edits :**

Within my ApplicationOAuthProvider

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (UserManager<MyUser> userManager = _userManagerFactory())
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });                
            var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserName", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Password", context.Password));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("token", context.Ticket.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ClientId", context.ClientId));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
    }
```

I am unable to find the token though the Startup.cs contains the code for the same. I am new to this concept plz let me know if I am wrong somewhere. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to invoke your `http://localhost:8089/token` it will hit the `OAuthServiceProvider`

Comment: @Eldho do you mean once the use is authenticated within Login action I need to invoke the uri. Is it ?

Comment: Just invoke the `yoursite/token` and pass the `credentials` in the `body`

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this work for me
**ApplicationOAuthProvider**

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

> I just need to invoke the `mysite/token` pass the credentials in the body it will return the `token` and user details.

**Update**
Invoking from js

```
  $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
             var user = new Object();
             user.username = $('#txtUserName').val();
             user.password = $('#txtPassword').val();
             user.grant_type = 'password';

             $.ajax({

                 url: 'http://localhost:61660/token',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 data: user,
                 success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                     debugger;
                     console.log(data);
                     window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token);
                     window.location.href = 'http://localhost:61660/UserHome/Index';

                 },
                 error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert("Invalid username/password")
                     console.log('Error in Operation');
                 }
             });


         });
     });
```

[image]

Comment: How can I send the token in a Heaer to a client. Here in my case fiddler/Postman.

Comment: @Eldoh and wht abt authentication.

Comment: I dont get that, could you elaborate